# FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist in Flutter firebase ( Anonoymous sign in)

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am trying to connect my flutter project with firebase. I have followed all the instructions and also added the google services in the app/build.gradle file. I am trying to sign in anonymously but it gives me this error FirebaseApp with name [DEFAULT] doesn't exist

```
Future signInAnon() async{

  try{
    AuthResult result = await _auth.signInAnonymously();
    FirebaseUser user = result.user;
    return user;
  } catch(e){
    print(e.toString());
    return null;
  }


}
```

Comment: add apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  to android gradle

Answer (score 1):

add this line to your main  `Firebase.initializeApp();`

```
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
 

  await di.init();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```

also make sure that you added **firebase_core** package to your pubspec.yaml file
also make sure that you **enabled anonymous** signing in authentication section in your fire base account

Comment: if that solved your question pls mark it as answer  "accept it"